# Second Datebtn.setText() inside switch case does not settext the selected date value & Datebtn text continues to show only the current date

Tags: settext

I have tried this button.set() in multiple ways by doing this inside dateonset () method  and I get a null pointer exception there though the editText4 contains the valid text to set the button. I tried the route of Shared preferences as I suspected the edittext4 is empty. Finally I tried this method to initialize the Datebtn inside the Onclick method from view. Here I don't get a null pointer exception but Datebtn.setText() inside switch case does not settext the selected date value & Datebtn text continues to show only the current date that was set in the onCreateView () method. I think I am missing something trivial.

```
public class AFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private DataManipulator dh;
    public Button           Datebtn;
    private Calendar        mCalen;
    private int             day;
    private int             month;
    private int             year;
    public String           myEditText4;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.afragment, container, false );
        Button b1 = (Button)view.findViewById( R.id.Button01 );
        b1.setOnClickListener( this );
        Button Datebtn = (Button)view.findViewById( R.id.datepickerbutton );
        mCalen = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = mCalen.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
        month = mCalen.get( Calendar.MONTH );
        year = mCalen.get( Calendar.YEAR );
        Datebtn.setText( day + " / " + (month + 1) + " / " + year );
        myEditText4 = (String)Datebtn.getText();
        Datebtn.setOnClickListener( this );
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressLint( "CutPasteId" )
    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Button Datebtn = (Button)view.findViewById( R.id.datepickerbutton );

        switch( view.getId() ) {
            case (R.id.datepickerbutton):
                DatePickerFragment newDateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newDateFragment.setStyle( 1, 1 );
                newDateFragment.show( getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker" );
                Datebtn.setText( myEditText4 );
                break;

            case (R.id.Button01):
                View editText1 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.ppl );
                View editText2 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.litres );
                View editText3 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.odo );
                String myEditText1 = ((TextView)editText1).getText().toString();
                String myEditText2 = ((TextView)editText2).getText().toString();
                String myEditText3 = ((TextView)editText3).getText().toString();
                dh = new DataManipulator( context );
                if( myEditText1 != "" & myEditText2 != "" & myEditText3 != "" & myEditText4 != "" ) {
                    dh.insert( myEditText1, myEditText2, myEditText3, myEditText4 );
                    Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(), "Submit Successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    EditText text1 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.ppl );
                    text1.setText( "" );
                    EditText text2 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.litres );
                    text2.setText( "" );
                    EditText text3 = (EditText)getView().findViewById( R.id.odo );
                    text3.setText( "" );
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText( context.getApplicationContext(), "Values can not be empty!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint( "ValidFragment" )
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get( Calendar.YEAR );
            int month = c.get( Calendar.MONTH );
            int day = c.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
            return new DatePickerDialog( getActivity(), this, year, month, day );
        }

        public void onDateSet( DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay ) {
            int year = selectedYear;
            int month = selectedMonth;
            int day = selectedDay;
            myEditText4 = (day + " / " + (month + 1) + " / " + year);

            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the state of all variables, I was able to figure out the issue. Here is the solution
1) When I did Datebtn inside the onDateSet method, I was actually trying to get the Datebtn object from the Datepicker view. The Datebtn is not in this fragment and hence it gives null pointer exception
2) I then attempted to get the parent fragment from inside the onDateSet using fragment manager object and findFragmentByTag("AFragment"). This is also returned a null pointer because "AFragment" tag is not defined for the AFragment layout xml or AFragment class
3) Then I tried to get a valid AFragment object from fragment manager object using findFragmentByID (R.id.fragment_container). At this step, I got a valid AFragment object handle in DatePickerFragment class. I was then able to do setText on the Datebtn in AFragment class from DatePickerFragment class

Here is how the working code for DatePickerFragment's onDateSet looks

```
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        int year = selectedYear;
        int month = selectedMonth;
        int day = selectedDay;
        myEditText4 = (day + " / " + (month + 1) + " / " + year);
        FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
        Fragment parFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        Button dbtn = (Button) parFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.datepickerbutton);
        dbtn.setText(myEditText4);
    return;
    }
```